# Purpose of semantic objects in Fiori

Tags: sapui5

I understand that *semantic object* is a business entity, and Fiori launchpad is responsible for doing intent based navigation which is again combination of semantic object and action.

But, What I'm not able to understand is why do we need to use *semantic objects* in configuration part and why do we actually create them in `/UI2/SEMOBJ`.

Please make it clear for me.